# Find multiple values in different lines using command-line | CMD

Tags: command-line, cmd, hl7

I have multiple results (Radiology, Labs, Pathology, Transcriptions) for the same patient in a file and I am only interested in getting results for a set of particular values. For example: I want to look for a radiology report on the first line and patient MRN 123456789 on the second line. 
Can this be achieved using findstr? Thanks

```
MSH|^~\&|RADIOLOGY|1|SCM||20150303||ORU|20150303|T|2.3|20150303
PID||1111111|123456789^^^MRN_SB^||TEST^PATIENT^^^||19000101||^^||
PV1|1|E|ER^ER^1^SB||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
ORC|RE|36543654|36543654|3003487889
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
SET "found="
SET "mrn=%1"
FOR /f "delims=" %%o IN (q29931949.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=|" %%a IN ("%%o") DO (
  IF DEFINED found IF "%%a"=="PID" (
   SET "$2=%%o"
   CALL :report "%%b" "%%c" "%%d"
  )
  SET "found="
  IF "%%a"=="MSH" IF "%%b"=="RADIOLOGY" SET found=Y
  IF "%%a"=="MSH" IF "%%c"=="RADIOLOGY" SET found=Y
  IF DEFINED found SET "$1=%%o"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

:report
SET "field=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED field GOTO :EOF
FOR /f "tokens=1delims=^^" %%r IN ("%~1") DO SET "field=%%r"
IF "%field%"=="%mrn%" FOR  /F "tokens=1*delims==" %%r In ('set $') DO ECHO(%%s
shift
GOTO report
```

I used a file named `q29931949.txt` containing your data for my testing.

You don't really supply enough information to produce a result. For instance, is "MRN" a required data item?

This procedure will find two consecutive lines, the first one having "MSH" in he first column and "RADIOLOGY" in the second or third and the second line having "PID" in the first column snd either the second, third or fourth column containing the target number.

You'd run the routine using *thisbatchaname* 123456789

It accepts the parameter `123456789` and assigns that to `mrn`.

It then reads the file and assigns each line in tun to `%%o`, and tokenises the line on `|`, applying tokens 1-4 to `%%a..%%d` rspectively.

The main loop sets `found` to empty and then to `Y` only if the first field is `MSH` and the second or thid `RADIOLOGY`. If the `found` flag is set, the original line in `%%o` is applied to `$1`. Only if `found` is set at the start of the loop (which means that the previous line is `MSH/RADIOLOGY`) will the routine `:report` be called after `$2` has the original contents of the second line assigned.

The `:report` routine sets `field` to the first parameter to see whether there are remaining parameters to process. The `for` then assigns the part of the field up to the first caret (`^`) to `field`. If this matches the `mrn` input from the command line, then the `$` variables are `echo`ed to the console (you don't say what you actually want to do with the data). Regardless, the remaining parameters are checked.

The reson for checking the second/third(/fourth) parameter is to cater for the presence or absence of data in the fields as consecutive `|` characters are interpreted as a single delimiter.

Comment: MRN is the patient identifier and is needed in every HL7 message the same goes for the type of report mentioned in the MSH segment. Nothing happens when I call the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Find a HL7 parser library for Your programming/scripting language of choice and use it. It is not worth it to write a HL7 parser from scratch. There should be libraries available for all popular languages that You can use.

If You then have specific questions, feel free to ask again.